# Problem with displaying a diagram after a half move

Tags: xskak

The following example inputs 4 moves with \hidemoves.
Displaying the board after the first 2 moves ( 4 half moves) is OK.
Displaying the board after another move is also OK.
However, displaying the board after one half move (White's fourth move)
leads to a wrong position.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}        
    \newchessgame[id=demo]

    \hidemoves{%
    1.d4 Nf6 
    2.c4 g6 
    3.Nc3 Bg7 
    4. Nd5 d6 
    }
%\xskakset{style=styleC}        
\printchessgame[stopmoveid=2b]

\chessboard[tinyboard, setfen =\xskakget{pastfen}]

\printchessgame[initmoveid=3w, stopmoveid=3b]

Diagramm with two half moves later.\\    
\chessboard[tinyboard, setfen =\xskakget{pastfen}]

 \printchessgame[initmoveid=4w, stopmoveid=4w]

 A very strange move. \\
 However, that is not the expected position.\\
 \chessboard[tinyboard, setfen =\xskakget{pastfen}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on a side effect with your `\xskakget{pastfen}`. `\printchessgame` does change the moveid, it has to do it during the processing, but this wasn't meant to be used outside.

I will think about it if it would be make sense if `\printchessgame` sets the number to the last processed move (perhaps) but until then you shouldn't rely on the moveid to have a definite value and better it explictly in the chessboard (and use nextfen, as you want the position after the move):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

    \newchessgame[id=demo]

    \hidemoves{%
    1.d4 Nf6
    2.c4 g6
    3.Nc3 Bg7
    4.Nd5 d6
    }
%\xskakset{style=styleC}
\printchessgame[stopmoveid=2b]

\chessboard[tinyboard, moveid=2b, setfen =\xskakget{nextfen}]

\printchessgame[initmoveid=3w, stopmoveid=3b]

Diagramm with two half moves later.\\
\chessboard[tinyboard, moveid=3b,setfen =\xskakget{nextfen}]

 \printchessgame[initmoveid=4w, stopmoveid=4w]


A very strange move. \\
However, that is not the expected position.\\
\chessboard[tinyboard, moveid=4w,setfen =\xskakget{nextfen}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought a bit regarding the value of moveid after a printing, and imho even if I change the code to set the value to stopmoveid, you should better not get used to rely on it. As soon as variations and comments are involved, or if the boards are printed in floats etc the moveid can be wrong again. Better set it always explicitly in the board.